# Checking the openness and closedness of a continuous mapping

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ be a function, where $\tau$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R},$ defined by $f(x)=e^x.$

a) Is $f$ an open map ?

b) Is $f$ a closed map ?

**My attempt:**

We can see that $f$ is a homeomorphism between  $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ and $((0,\infty),\tau_1),$ where $\tau_1$ is the subspace topology on $(0,\infty)$ induced by $\tau.$ So, $f$ is both open and closed mapping.

But the solution says that $f$ is open but not closed.
This means that there exists a closed set $C$ in $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ such that $f(C)$ is not closed.

I feel like my logic for $f$ being open is also flawed.
I am stuck here. Please help.
Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would like to add one more point. Just got it and didn't want to miss it out.

Take $(-\infty,1].$ This is closed in $\mathbb{R}.$ But $f((-\infty,1])=(0,e]$ is not closed.

Comment: So, $f$ is not a closed mapping.

Comment: That works as well!

Answer (score 1):

> We can see that $f$ is a homemorphism between $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ and $((0, \infty), \tau_1)$, where $\tau_1$ is the subspace topology on $(0, \infty)$ induced by $\tau$. So, $f$ is both open and closed mapping.

There is a problem here. What you mean is that $f': \mathbb{R} \rightarrow f (\mathbb{R}) = (0, \infty)$ is a homeomorphism (thus continuous, open, and closed), but this does not imply that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ obtained by expanding the range is also open and closed.

We can see that $f$ is open since the image of the domain, $(0, \infty)$, is open in the codomain $\mathbb{R}$. So, given that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, $f (U) = f' (U)$ is open in $(0, \infty)$ and hence also open in the codomain $\mathbb{R}$.

However, it's easy to show that $f$ is not closed: take the image of the trivially closed set $\mathbb{R}$ of the domain itself - it is $(0, \infty)$, which certainly isn't closed in $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: Do not use $\mapsto$ for $\to$. The notation $\mapsto$ is used only to indicate the image of a particular element $x$ under the mapping.

Comment: Thank you very much @K. Jiang